# What is replacement of .deb packages to automatically install dependency in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

In Ubuntu I install some software via deb packages (dpkg -i), because in "apt-get install" old versions of software. But I have to manually install all dependency to deb package. How to avoid this?

For example installation of bareos 16 version in Ubuntu. I install it from deb package via [official site](http://download.bareos.org/bareos/release/latest/xUbuntu_16.04/amd64/).

But there are other files on [page](http://download.bareos.org/bareos/release/latest/xUbuntu_16.04/) (Packages, Release, Sources ...).

[image: other files]

What should I use and how to replace deb package and install dependency automatically? For example in CentOS as far as I know there is file .repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the Bareos community repository, you first need to download and import their key:

```
curl http://download.bareos.org/bareos/release/latest/xUbuntu_16.04/Release.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

then add the repository:

```
echo deb http://download.bareos.org/bareos/release/latest/xUbuntu_16.04/ / | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bareos.list
```

before updating:

```
sudo apt update
```

You will then be able to install Bareos packages and their dependencies using `apt install bareos`, and they will be upgraded by `apt upgrade` whenever new releases are made available.

Comment: Thanks. Do I understand correctly, that now when I want to install concrete package I have to install from such command
"sudo apt install bareos-filedaemon_16.2.4-12.1_amd64"
 instead of 
"dpkg -i bareos-filedaemon_16.2.4-12.1_amd64.deb"?

Comment: No, you’d just run `sudo apt install bareos-filedaemon` (without downloading the package beforehand).

Answer (score 0):

Use apt:

```
$ apt-get install ./file.deb
```

Comment: Thanks. When need to update package what should I use, installing new .deb file or something like "apt-get update" of previous file?